# How to get the width of an SVG tspan element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm trying to get the rendered width of a `tspan` element (located inside a `text` element) in SVG.

This is my markup:

```
<text>
    <tspan>Value 1</tspan>
    <tspan>Value 2</tspan>
</text>
```

Visually, I want value 1 to float left, while value 2 floats right, so that a multiple elements will align as such:

```
Value 1                                                                   Value 2
Value 10                                                                 Value 20
Value 100                                                               Value 200
Value 1000                                                             Value 2000
```

Since I want the width of the `tpsan` ("value 1"/"value 2") and not the text element, I can't use `getBBox()`, as that method doesn't apply to `tspan` elements.

Oddly enough, using jQuery's `width()` method will return the correct value in Chrome, but returns `NaN` in Firefox. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps taking a look at the console & the core function for .width will yield an explanation?

Comment: It seems jQuery just uses offsetWidth -- I tried consoling out just the offsetWidth values, Chrome gives me values, Firefox gives me 'undefined'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) to find the screen-space bounding box of the `tspan`. I've tested and found this to work in Safari v5.0.4, Firefox 3.6 and 4.0RC, and Opera 11. However, it [fails with Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76886), v10.0.648.151 and v11.0.696.14. (It returns a ClientRect with all values set to `0`.)

You'll have to transform this client-space rectangle into SVG coordinates by multiplying by the inverse of the screen transform matrix. Here's a working example:
http://phrogz.net/SVG/tspan_bounding_box.xhtml

Pair this with `offsetWidth` (which works in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox or Opera) and you have a solution that should work in all browsers that support SVG well.

Comment: This certainly seems to work, though it doesn't seem to be quite as accurate (or maybe it's more accurate) than offsetWidth. Here's the real-world example of how I'm using it: http://jsfiddle.net/ArmRM/6411/  I didn't use the matrixTransform values, since Firefox offerred .width and .height attributes -- are these not supported in Opera / Safari?

Comment: I haven't had time to look at your example code yet, but I'm guessing that `offsetWidth` might be specified in screen units while you need to transform the units from screen space to SVG space, or further transformation values.

Comment: getClientBoundingRect will not work in all browsers. I think getComputedTextLength is the best way.

Answer (score 13):

After trying multiple solutions I found [getComputedTextLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength) to be the most accurate way to get the width of an svg tspan. It is also well supported and behaves the same way on different browsers. I also found that the best way to get the height of a tspan is simply to read the font-size attribute.

Comment: Note: This get's the width of the actual characters, not the bounding box of the tspans.  The font characters can be slightly larger than the tspan bounding box.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpfull

Comment: I ended up using this, in order to simulate justification in a paragraph text element which contains multiple lines which are tspans. Using width of each one, it was then possible to left-justify and center-justify all the spans by changing their x value in the relation to the preceding tspan above. To left-justify spans, usually one has to do nothing, but if for some reason they are not already all left-justified, setting all x values to 0 does this and is the easiest thing to do.