# Not able to get the width of tspan in SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

The width seems to be zero (or null) always for an svg:text tspan element in Firefox & Safari.

The jQuery functions width() and height() returns 0 for SVG tspan text elements in Firefox 11 and IE 9. 
In both Chrome 17 and 19 they work as expected.
I have also tried usinf offsetWidth & getComputedTextLength() both returns 0 or null.

this is my query code:

```
$('svg #aitext-2-front-middle').find('tspan').each(function(i){                
   var currWidth = $(this).width();
   console.log(currWidth);
});
```

This is the svg part:

```
<text id="aitext-2-front-middle" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 81.7744 155.248)">
    <tspan x="66.287" y="57.6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">lightweight UIs using </tspan>
    <tspan x="39.72" y="72" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">Adobe Illustrator CS5 (or above) </tspan>
    <tspan x="40.146" y="86.4" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">along with some free resources. </tspan>
    <tspan x="79.385" y="100.8" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">Let’s get started.</tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: which platform are you on? i'm writing this text on chrome 34 ...

Comment: Thanks for comment..Yes I am using chrome 34.. but chrome it is working great but i have problem with firefox and safari

Answer (score 0):

A slight correction of your code makes it work in:

- chrome (34)
- firefox (28)
- ie (ie10 standard mode and mimicking ie9)
- safari 5.1.7 (windows)

have a look at [this demo](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.svg.qry.tspan.width.html) to see it working.

use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('svg #aitext-2-front-middle').find('tspan').each(function(i, e){
       var currWidth;

       currWidth = $(this).width();
       if (!currWidth) {
           currWidth = e.getBoundingClientRect().width;
           if ((!currWidth) && (e.parentNode.getBBox)) {
               currWidth = e.parentNode.getBBox().width;
           }
       }

       console.log(currWidth);
    });
});
```

unfortunately the implicit browser switches appear to be necessary. in particular, the `tspan` element does not have a `getBBox` method in ie, whereas the `text` element has.

**EDIT**:

an alternative might be to call `getComputedTextLength()` (kudos go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729371/588916)). Its output has been incorporated into the live demo

Comment: Everything you've posted has been answered in the question itself.

Comment: @Archer no it hasn't - none of the browsers are close to the current versions, there is no mention of the jquery version at all nor of the context in which the js code snippet is used.

Comment: Which version of FF? When do you call the code? Do you get the error with the live demo?

Comment: @Pankaj Right, i've corrected the issue and i've updated the live demo.

Comment: This wasn't a bad answer at all (especially for 2014!): x of an element is the sum of its siblings' width, and getComputedTextLength() will get us the width. Consider Chromium only fixed the getBBox bug now (6 years later), and [for WebKit the bug still exists, bug report here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211282).